# Proving that the power set of a Von Neumann number is itself a Von Neumann number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently learned about Von Neumann numbers, which defines the natural numbers recursively by $0 = \emptyset$ and $n + 1 = n \cup \{n\} = \{0, 1, ..., n - 1\}$. While investigating their properties, I observed that the Von Neumann number $X$ seems to satisfy $((S \in T) \land (T \in X)) \implies (S \in X)$; any element *of* an element of such a set is itself an element of that set.

Now, I want to show that for a Von Neumann number $X$, $P(X)$ is also a Von Neumann number. That is, **I want to show that for every set $S$ where $((A \in B) \land (B \in S)) \implies (A \in S)$, the power set $P(S)$ satisfies this property as well: $(C \in D) \land (D \in P(S)) \implies (C \in P(S))$**.

Here is some work I've done so far:

- $P(S)$ by definition is the set of all subsets of $S$. So, any element *of* an element of $P(S)$ is itself an element of $S$ (because an element of $P(S)$ is subset of $S$). That is, $(C \in D) \land (D \in P(S)) \implies (C \in S)$.
- However, we want to show that $(C \in D) \land (D \in P(S)) \implies (C \in P(S))$. From above, we know that $(C \in D) \land (D \in P(S)) \implies (C \in S)$. Thus, it suffices to show that $C \in S \implies C \in P(S)$. This is where I am stuck.

Can someone provide some hints or insights to prove this interesting property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. In particular, $P(n)$ is not a von Neumann numeral for all $n > 1$.

In particular, if $n > 1$, then $\{1\} \in P(n)$. But $\{1\}$ is not a von Neumann number, and every element of a von Neumann number is itself a von Neumann number.

You conflate being a von Neumann number with being a transitive set (a set $S$ with the property that $\forall a \in S \forall b \in a (b \in S)$). It is true that the power set of a transitive set will itself be transitive. It’s also true that all von Neumann ordinals are transitive. What is not true is that all transitive sets are von Neumann ordinals.

We show that the power set of a transitive set is transitive. For suppose $S$ is transitive. Note that transitivity is, by the definition of $\subseteq$, the statement $\forall a \in S (a \subseteq S)$.

Suppose $b \in a \in P(S)$. Then $b \in a \subseteq S$, so $b \in S$. By transitivity of $S$, $b \subseteq S$. Thus, $b \in P(S)$. This completes the proof that $P(S)$ is transitive.